# Partial application of an expression tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees, c#-5.0

I have an Expression in the following form:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = t => t.Value == "SomeValue";
```

Is it possible to create a 'partially applied' version of this expression:

```
Expression<Func<bool>> predicate = () => t.Value == "SomeValue";
```

NB This expression is never actually compiled or invoked, it is merely inspected to generate some SQL.

Comment: The short answer would be "yes"; the approach would be "an ExpressionVisitor that substitutes ParameterExpression with ConstantExpression". I'm not at a pc, but if you need an example I'll be back later

Comment: @MarcGravell Excellent, thanks Marc. I'd been looking at ExpressionVisitors, will try your approach.

Comment: The only way you could do that is if you are willing to set the variable `t` at the time of closure.  There's no value to get from the `ParameterExpression` while you visit the expression.  You'd have to provide that up front.  Would that still work knowing you have to do that upfront?

Comment: The wording of 'closed' is wrong here. Seems more like a 'composed' (or 'curried', if you will understand that way) expression.

Comment: @leppie I would have used the term "partial application"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be easily achieved by writing a custom ExpressionVisitor and replacing the parameter with a constant expression that you have captured in a closure:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ReplaceVisitor<T> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly T _instance;
    public ReplaceVisitor(T instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return Expression.Constant(_instance);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> predicate = t => t.Value == "SomeValue";
        var foo = new Foo { Value = "SomeValue" };
        Expression<Func<bool>> result = Convert(predicate, foo);

        Console.WriteLine(result.Compile()());
    }

    static Expression<Func<bool>> Convert<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, T instance)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(
            new ReplaceVisitor<T>(instance).Visit(expression.Body)
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
Expression predicate2 = Expression.Invoke(predicate, Expression.Constant(new T() { Value = "SomeValue"}));
Expression<Func<bool>> predicate3 = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(predicate2);
```

Don't know if this is easily parseable to generate SQL however (it works when compiled - I tried).

Comment: I used this and it worked when converted to SQL. Less complex than above. Great :)